# How to use CSS isolation in Blazor via rendertreebuilder?

Tags: css, blazor

My component file MyComponent.cs

```
public class MyComponent : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

        builder.OpenElement(1, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", "my-class");
        builder.AddContent(3, "My component 1");

        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

My css-file MyComponent.cs.css

```
.my-class {
background-color: red;}
```

css is not added to assembly

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do isolation Css using a class.  I tried to figure it out a while ago and failed.  I'll watch to see if anyone comes up with a solution.

Comment: For css isolation to work, At first your css file name should be MyComponent.razor.css but not MyComponent.cs.css

Comment: @SurinderSingh -  Your missing the point - there's no Razor file here, just a pure dotnetcore class implementing `ComponentBase`.

Comment: I need a component with a dynamic html teg. But I can create it only in a method RenderTreeBuilder. Does it mean that I can't make a component with dynamic tag and css isolation at the same time?